# Java date function which is not deprecated

Tags: java, date

I simply need to print the date of the day on the console in this format: `Day.Month.Year`. Example: `03.10.09`

Code:

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
Date s =  c.getTime(); 
System.out.println(s);
```

The console prints:

```
Sat Oct 03 13:33:36 CEST 2009
```

I could do it with a case statement, but I am sure there is something more elegant, which I simply didn't find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat in the java.text package.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class FormatDemo
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
      Date s =  c.getTime();
      DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
      System.out.println(formatter.format(s));
   }
}
```

Comment: gee..

 now i found http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/java-date.htm this post.

SimpleDateFormat is exactly what i need, thx for help.

Answer (score 5):

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
Date s =  c.getTime();
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy").format(s);
System.out.println(dateString);
```